# Python/TensorFlow - Custom loss function on 2D array target

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

I need to use a custom loss function with my CNN. The target variable `y_true` is a 2D array of shape (6, 8). Using standard NumPy operations, my loss function is supposed to do this:

```py
def loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
    # loss function: maximise sum of each e^(-ax^2) where x is the distance between each cell and the true peak,
    # weighted by the prediction confidence
    peaks_i = np.argwhere(y_true == 1.0)
    num_peaks = len(peaks_i)
    score_array = np.zeros_like(y_true, dtype=np.float64)
    for peak_row, peak_col in peaks_i:
        score_array -= np.array([
            # dist squared = (i - peak_row) ** 2 + (j - peak_col) ** 2
            [np.exp(-0.35 * ((i - peak_row) ** 2 + (j - peak_col) ** 2)) for j in range(y_true.shape[1])] for i in range(y_true.shape[0])
        ]) / num_peaks
    return np.sum(score_array * y_pred)
```

Unfortunately, we can't use this because tensorflow requires us to use its own data types (tensors). I have no experience with this format so I asked ChatGPT to make it compatible, and after fixing a lot of float64/int32 type issues (it was very picky), I got this:

```py
def loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
    peaks_i = tf.cast(tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1.0)), dtype=tf.int64)
    scaler_factor = tf.cast(1 / tf.shape(peaks_i)[0], dtype=tf.float32)
    score_array = tf.zeros_like(y_true, dtype=tf.float32)
    for peak in peaks_i:
        distances = tf.square(tf.range(tf.shape(y_true)[0]) - tf.cast(peak[0], dtype=tf.int32)) + \
                    tf.square(tf.range(tf.shape(y_true)[1]) - tf.cast(peak[1], dtype=tf.int32))
        exp_factors = -0.35 * tf.cast(distances[:, tf.newaxis], dtype=tf.float32)
        exp_distances = tf.exp(exp_factors)
        score_array -= exp_distances
    return tf.math.scalar_mul(scaler_factor, tf.reduce_sum(score_array * y_pred))
```

which is giving me an error that I can no longer decipher:

```
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_28/2075680276.py", line 21, in loss_func
      distances = tf.square(tf.range(tf.shape(y_true)[0]) - tf.cast(peak[0], dtype=tf.int32)) + \
Node: 'loss_func/while/add'
Incompatible shapes: [32] vs. [6]
     [[{{node loss_func/while/add}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_14166]
```

I'm not sure how I'm getting a shape of 32 at any point, and that shape of 6 should certainly be (6, 8), so there's some kind of problem with dimensions here. It doesn't help that I can't seem to print anything out as this is running so I'm working blind here.

To reproduce this:

1. See my notebook which is hosted on kaggle: [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/nick2440/urop-data-analysis)
2. Run the first three cells (up to and including "Process Data"). The data I'm working with should be there and work seamlessly. This cell shows a sample of what one of the `y_true` looks like.
3. Scroll down to the cell called "Split Datasets" and run that cell
4. Run the cell below that, which contains the erroneous loss function.

Note that in this case, the value of `scaler_factor` should always be 1 since there is only 1 entry in the `y_true` arrays equal to 1.0. In general though, it will be 1/n, where n is the number of 1s in the `y_true` array. The idea of my loss function is that we look at where it is confident, and if it close in distance to the true peaks, then we still score it well even if it is 1 square away, but we penalise when it is confident far from any peak. I'm aware this logic isn't perfect, and will make amendments later, but I'd just like to get the function to be accepted by TensorFlow to start.

Putting `tensor[:, tf.newaxis]` on different arrays in my loss function led to different errors and sometimes different shapes. I figure this creates a new dimension in my array but am not sure this is the correct way to do it as currently the shapes are not even correct.

Thanks for any help!